# Hibernate Session.merge() hits second level cache, but saveOrUpdate does not

Tags: java, hibernate, ehcache

I have a requirement to frequently synchronize a large collection of detached entities to the database, and am wanting to do so with `Session.saveOrUpdate()`. These entities are of the same type and have several OneToMany CascadeType.ALL associations.

This is currently a performance hotspot that slows down my application (it's taking minutes and I need it to take seconds). To solve this, I've looked to Hibernate's second level cache (with EhCache).

My problem is that each time I attempt a `saveOrUpdate` on these entities, Hibernate's statistics show I accumulate many puts, but always 0 hits and 0 misses. And (interestingly) the puts continue to accumulate each time I attempt the `saveOrUpdate` again.

The good news is I have been able to refactor my application to use `Session.merge()` instead of `saveOrUpdate`. With this, I am successfully hitting the second level cache and achieving a noticeable performance improvement, and my detached entities and their associations are synchronized to the database correctly.

My question is why isn't the second level cache hit when I invoke `saveOrUpdate`? If I could use `saveOrUpdate`, my code changes would have been minimal. I've glanced at the Hibernate source code's `saveOrUpdate` implementation and found this `TODO` that seemingly (without fully understanding the code) bypasses the second level cache:

https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.2.10/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/event/internal/DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java#L295-L305

Is that the answer? This capability just hasn't been implemented yet? My Hibernate version is 5.2.10, and I confirmed the current Hibernate version (6.1.2) still contains to the TODO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `saveOrUpdate` was deprecated in 6.0 with `merge` being the replacement for it, the migration is good. This method will be removed in the future and there will be no further feature development for it.